# How can I read the message from 5sim.net with Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I can get numbers from 5sim.net with Python, but I don't know how to read the code that came to the number I got. I couldn't find it in the documentation. How can I read the code from the number?

```
import requests

token = 'Your token'
country = 'bangladesh'
operator = 'any'
product = 'telegram'

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
}

response = requests.get('https://5sim.net/v1/user/buy/activation/' + country + '/' + operator + '/' + product, headers=headers)
```

This is how I get the number.

Answer (score 0):

You will get Order ID from `https://5sim.net/v1/user/buy/activation/` and then use `https://5sim.net/v1/user/check/ORDER_ID_HERE` to get the SMS, if sent.

```
orderCheckResp = requests.get(
    url='{}/{}'.format('https://5sim.net/v1/user/check', response['5347809455']),
    headers=headers
)
```